# Can I connect my D-Link to another access point?

Tags: wireless-router

I have a D-Link N300 and I want to connect it to another wireless router, so I may provide Internet access to my wired network in another room. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you disable the dhcp server on the N300 it should be OK.

If you're looking for expanding the wifi signal I sugest you read how to configure WDS (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System ) on both devices (usually just activate and enter the macaddress of one on the other).

If you wanna connect them by cable just connect a Rj45 UTP cable on one of a LAN port each device and it should be OK